# Rails: user.r.new when r is an iterator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have an array of classes that looks like this:

```
def resources
  [Brand, Chart, Component, Cover, Expression, Introduction, Mode, Preference, Price, Template, User, UserNote]
end
```

How can I build one of each in a loop with a parent association, i.e.:

```
resources.each do |r|
  current_user.r.new
end
```

Not sure how to convert the `r` to a child. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm, what happens if you add validations to a Brand, that on creation it requires a value, then your each loop will need to check whether its creating a Brand record then add that value. If you add the "has_many :brands" association to the user class, then rails will automatically give you the "current_user.brand" so you can call the following: "current_user.brand = Brand.new". I think that for loop is going to make your code too *DRY*, or use Kengo's answer if it's a must.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all associations are defined as has_many, you can tableize models and use send method like this.

```
resources.each do |r|
  current_user.send(r.to_s.tableize).new
end
```

If there is any belongs_to association included, it's better to have association names array in resources method instead of classes.

```
def resources
  %w(brands charts component ....)
end

resources.each do |r|
  current_user.send(r).new
end
```